# Why can't I call a function direct when document loads with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the $(document).ready function from jQuery. It seems that I can't call a function directly with it. I can't figure out why. It gives an error when I try to find the canvas with getElementById.

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var test="this is a test";
var canvas;
var ctx;

$(document).ready( function(){ 
    init(); 
}); 

function init() {               
    console.log (test);
    canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');      
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
    No HTML5 support.
</canvas>       
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

This works too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var test="this is a test";
var canvas;
var ctx;

$(document).ready(function(){               
    console.log (test);
    canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');      
}); 


</script>

</head>

<body>
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
    No HTML5 support.
</canvas>       
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

But this gives an error...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var test="this is a test";
var canvas;
var ctx;

$(document).ready(init()); 

function init() {               
    console.log (test);
    canvas=document.getElementById('canvas'); // <= Error here!
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');      
}


</script>

</head>

<body>
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
    No HTML5 support.
</canvas>       
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Kind regards!

Comment: I've added a very extensive explanation about callbacks, to explain in the best detailed way I could why init() won't work :)

Answer (score 3):

it's in this line:

```
$(document).ready(init());
```

You are actually calling the init-function immediately and passing the result of that as the argument to the ready-function.
As this line executes before the DOM is ready, the init-function fails.

You want to change to this instead:

```
$(document).ready(init);
```

That is, pass the actual init-function to the ready-function instead of it's result.

Answer (score 1):

You should try without `()` like this `$(document).ready(init);`

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on *how* you want to use your `init()` function.

The syntax for `$(document).ready` is: `$(document).ready(callBackFunction);`

---

This means you must provide a **callback**, which is:

1. a **function object**, as an object it must be written **without** the "()" parentheses (like in the definition above), because we are not "calling" it in order to execute it! Instead we're providing a *reference* of the function to `.ready()`, so JQuery's internal code for `.ready()` can "find" and call the function by itself
2. or an **anonymous function** in the form of `function() {..somecode..}`, inside `.ready(...)`.

What you do instead is providing a **function call**, that's why it doesn't work: you're not providing a function, but in some sense the "result" of a function which is most of the times **not** a function object (but a variable, or undefined if a `return` statement is not present).

---

So, if `init()` is intended to be a **complete substitute** of the ready()'s callback just do:

```
$(document).ready(init); // we're passing an object now not a "result" of
                         // a function, so no "()" needed
```

If instead you wish to add later some other operations to perform other than `init()`, call `init()` (remember that *call -> parentheses*, as said before) in an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // anonymous callback function
    init(); // we're calling init inside a function now,
            // so "()" are needed in order to execute it
    ... other stuff ...
});
```

---

For the curious ones: `$(document).ready(init());` **will** actually work if the code is like:

```
function init2()
{
     ... real init function;
}

function init()
{
     return init2; // function "returns" a function object...
}

$(document).ready(init()); // init() is "substituted" by a function object
                           // reference to init2(), so it works
```

(There's not much sense in doing that, but it can explain better the theory behind callbacks).

Comment: Thanks Cranio. I wasn't aware of callback functions. Still learning Javascript and this is something I have got to learn.

Answer (score 0):

call init() method in onload event of body tag

```
<body onload="init()">
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
init();
});
```

for more event details: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: What does that `.addEventListener()` call have to do with anything? You've basically repeated the OP's first syntax but added in an unrelated line of code.

Comment: check details for addEventListener() : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: I know what the `addEventListener()` does in a general sense - what I'm saying is it has nothing to do with this question. Why do you think it will help to add that line of code to the OP's code? Your code is saying that if the "deviceready" event occurs then the `onDeviceReady` function should be called but you haven't defined an `onDeviceReady` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line  `$(document).ready(init());`  to `$(document).ready(init);`

Link
http://jsfiddle.net/rcDue/2/